# How prove this inequality generalized from 1969 IMO problem 6

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, convex-analysis, contest-math

> Let 
>   $x_{1},x_{2},y_{1},y_{2},z_{1},z_{2},w_{1},w_{2} $ are all positive numbers, and such
>   $$x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}-w^3_{1}>0,\; \text{ and }\;x_{2}y_{2}z_{2}-w^3_{2}>0.$$
>   show that
>   $$\dfrac{16}{(x_{1}+x_{2})(y_{1}+y_{2})(z_{1}+z_{2})-(w_{1}+w_{2})^3}\le\dfrac{1}{x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}-w^3_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{x_{2}y_{2}z_{2}-w^3_{2}}.$$

This problem is created by me, and the background is the 1969 IMO problem 6,

please see: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=363659&sid=efafc24957d8919546afe4254638aea6#p363659

Thank you everyone for showing a proof, I still can't prove it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the following.

It is a partial answer, clarifying the situation (for me :-)).

At first we consider the set $D=\{(x,y,z,w)\in (0;\infty)^4: xyz>w^3\}$. We claim that the set $D$ is convex. To show this it suffice to check that the function $g(x,y,z)=–(xyz)^{1/3}$ is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

The [Hessian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix)

$$H(g)=\frac 19\left\|
\begin{matrix}
2x^{-5/3}y^{1/3}z^{1/3} & -x^{-2/3}y^{-2/3}z^{1/3} & -x^{-2/3}y^{1/3}z^{-2/3}\\
-x^{-2/3}y^{-2/3}z^{1/3} & 2x^{1/3}y^{-5/3}z^{1/3} & -x^{-2/3}y^{-2/3}z^{1/3}\\
-x^{-2/3}y^{1/3}z^{-2/3} & -x^{-2/3}y^{-2/3}z^{1/3} & 2x^{1/3}y^{1/3}z^{-5/3}\\
\end{matrix}
\right\|$$

has the following [principal minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_minor#Other_applications)

$$\Delta_1=2x^{-5/3}y^{1/3}z^{1/3}\ge 0, \Delta_2=2x^{1/3}y^{-5/3}z^{1/3}\ge 0,
\Delta_3=2x^{1/3}y^{1/3}z^{-5/3}\ge 0,$$

$$\Delta_{12}=3x^{-4/3}y^{-4/3}z^{2/3}\ge 0, \Delta_{13}=3x^{-4/3}y^{2/3}z^{-4/3}\ge 0, 
\Delta_{23}=3x^{1/3}y^{-4/3}z^{-4/3}\ge 0,$$

$$\Delta_{123}=0\ge 0.$$

Since all of them are non-negative, the matrix $H(g)$ is [positive semidefinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-semidefinite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices) , so the function $g$ [is convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties).

Hence the question inequality is equivalent to the convexity of the function $f(x,y,z,w)=\frac 1{xyz-w^3}$ defined on the convex set $D$, which again can be checked as positive semidefiniteness of the Hessian matrix $H(f)$. :-) But I had not done this check, so I don’t know the question inequality holds or not.

Comment: I tried the case $f:=\frac 1 {xyz-w^3}$ with Maple. See the output [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/4131568629/Hessian.pdf). Hope, this would be helpful.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks. I expected that there should be more inequalities needed for positive semidefiniteness of the Hessian matrix $H(f)$. All inequalities (2) holds strictly because $x,y,z,w$ are positive and $xyz>w^3$.

Comment: It's nice idea and This problem is prove it by there:http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2552804475

Comment: Nice solution. The Hessian matrix $H(f)$ is positive definite which can be verified by Maple codegen package (All its leading principal minors are positive. Surely can be calculate by hand).

Answer (score 1):

*Here is a proof*:

Let
$$a := \frac{1}{x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}-w^3_{1}}, \quad b := \frac{1}{x_{2}y_{2}z_{2}-w^3_{2}}.$$

We have
$$z_1 = \frac{w_1^3}{x_1y_1} + \frac{1}{ax_1y_1},
\quad z_2 = \frac{w_2^3}{x_2y_2} + \frac{1}{bx_2y_2}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$
 \left[(x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2)(z_1 + z_2) - (w_1 + w_2)^3\right](a + b) \ge 16
$$
or
\begin{align*}
 & \left[(x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2)\left(\frac{w_1^3}{x_1y_1} + \frac{w_2^3}{x_2y_2}\right) - (w_1 + w_2)^3\right](a + b)\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + (x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2)\left(\frac{1}{ax_1y_1} + \frac{1}{bx_2y_2}\right)(a + b) \ge 16
\end{align*}
which is true by Holder inequality. Indeed, by Holder inequality, we have
$$(x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2)\left(\frac{w_1^3}{x_1y_1} + \frac{w_2^3}{x_2y_2}\right) \ge  (w_1 + w_2)^3$$
and
$$(x_1 + x_2)(y_1 + y_2)\left(\frac{1}{ax_1y_1} + \frac{1}{bx_2y_2}\right)(a + b) \ge 16.$$

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

use the rearrangement inequality !

firstly, we assume that :

$x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}-w^3_{1}=a>0\; \text{ and }\;x_{2}y_{2}z_{2}-w^3_{2}=b>0$

by observing your inequality , you can find that :

$\dfrac{16}{(x_{1}+x_{2})(y_{1}+y_{2})(z_{1}+z_{2})-(w_{1}+w_{2})^3}\le\dfrac{1}{x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}-w^3_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{x_{2}y_{2}z_{2}-w^3_{2}}$$\Longrightarrow$

$\frac{16}{x_{2}y_{2}z_{1}+x_{1}y_{2}z_{1}+x_{2}y_{1}z_{1}+x_{1}y_{1}z_{2}+x_{1}y_{2}z_{2}+x_{2}y_{1}z_{2}+a+b-3w_{1}w_{2}(w_{1}+w_{2})}$$\le$$\frac{a+b}{ab}$

then, you can use the rearrangement inequality to get :

$4(a+b)^{2}\ge16ab$

the hint is :

firstly, we assume that :

$\frac{x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}}{w_{1}^3}\ge{1}$$,$$\frac{x_{2}y_{2}z_{2}}{w_{2}^3}\ge{1}$

where, $\frac{x_{1}}{w_{1}}$$\ge$$\frac{x_{2}}{w_{2}}$$,$
$\frac{y_{1}}{w_{1}}$$\ge$$\frac{y_{2}}{w_{2}}$$,$
$\frac{z_{1}}{w_{1}}$$\ge$$\frac{z_{2}}{w_{2}}$

if $a<b$, then we can use the rearrangement inequality to transfer :

$x_{2}y_{2}z_{1}+x_{1}y_{2}z_{1}+x_{2}y_{1}z_{1}+x_{1}y_{1}z_{2}+x_{1}y_{2}z_{2}+x_{2}y_{1}z_{2}$

to :

$3(x_{1}y_{1}z_{1}+x_{2}y_{2}z_{2})$

we also transfer :

$3w_{1}w_{2}(w_{1}+w_{2})$

to :

$3w_{1}^{3}+3w_{2}^{3}$

hence, your solution holds !